# TypeORM Or operator in query

Tags: typeorm

I want to run below mentioned query for Postgres but it is returning empty data.

```
const listOfAttendance = await this.attendanceRepository.find({
  where: {
    punchInDateTime: Between(dateFrom, dateTo),
    approvalStatus: status === 'ALL' ? ['PENDING', 'APPROVED', 'REJECTED'] : Equals(status),
    userId,
  },
})
```

I don't want to use Querybuilder for such a basic task.

Comment: Shouldn't be `approvalStatus: status === 'ALL' ? In(['PENDING', 'APPROVED', 'REJECTED']) : Equals(status),` ?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito , in is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are two mistakes in your query, when you want to look in list you should use `In()` function as we de in SQL queries `(where status in ('PENDING','APPROVED'..)` the second one is with `Equal()` function not `Equals()` *(without s)* :

```
    const listOfAttendance = await this.attendanceRepository.find({
  where: {
    punchInDateTime: Between(dateFrom, dateTo),
    approvalStatus: status === 'ALL' ? In(['PENDING', 'APPROVED', 'REJECTED']) : Equal(status),
    userId,
  },
})
```

for more details see [find-options](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md)

Comment: `import {In} from 'typeorm'` was my issue,  resolved. thanks,

Comment: I assume that Equals() function it's by  you not typeorm then, you're welcome ^^